# How to preserve order in shiny app using datatables when sorting in the app?

Tags: r, shiny, datatables, dt

The first column of the datatable consits of names, while the second column uses characters which are a combination of numeric with comma delimiters, and characters for other values, for example, "1,000" , "2,000", "19,000", "Data missing", "Data suppressed". Using `type = "num-fmt"` I am able to get the datatable to display correctly when I run it as a function by itself, i.e. "1,000", "2,000", "19,000", and when using sort in the Rstudio terminal its ordering is correct, and as such when first displayed in the R shiny app it works. However, when using the sort options in the shiny interface, the ordering no longer works correctly, i.e. "1,000" , "19,000" , "2,000".

My understanding is that I must do the sorting in the server, or use java script, but I don't know how.

```
ui <- dashboardPage(

box(title = "Industries from selected region",
                    status = "danger",
                    solidHeader = TRUE,
                    DT::dataTableOutput("industry_tbl"),
                    width = 6)
)




server <- function(input, output, session) {
values <- reactiveValues(direction = "Exports",
                           year = "2020",
                           partner_country = "Spain",
                           industry = "Mining",
                           home_country = "UK")

output$industry_tbl<- DT::renderDT({
    industry_table_server(new_data,
                       values$year,
                       values$partner_country,
                       values$direction,
                       values$home_country)
  })
```

function:

````
industry_table_server <- function(dataset,
                               selected_year, 
                               selected_country,
                               selected_direction,
                               selected_region){

this_selection <- dplyr::filter(dataset,
                                  Year == selected_year,
                                  Country == selected_country,
                                  Direction == selected_direction,
                                  `Area name` == selected_region) %>%
    select(Industry, value)

DT::datatable(this_selection , 
                colnames = c("Industry",
                             paste0("£millions")),
                filter = "none",
                rownames = TRUE,
                extensions = c('Buttons'),
                options = list(
                  dom = 'Bftip',
                  buttons = c('copy', 'excel', 'print'),
                  searchHighlight = TRUE,
                  searchDelay = 0,
                  selection = "single",
                  pageLength = 10, # Shows 10 results
                  lengthMenu = c(5, 10),
                  columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-right', targets = c(0,2)), list(targets = c(2), type = "num-fmt"))
                )
  )
} ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in [the datatables website](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.type), regarding the `type` option:

> Please note that if you are using server-side processing this option has no effect since the ordering and search actions are performed by a server-side script.

So you have to set `server = FALSE` in `renderDT`:

```
output$industry_tbl <- renderDT({
    industry_table_server(new_data,
                       values$year,
                       values$partner_country,
                       values$direction,
                       values$home_country)
}, server = FALSE)
```